# Vim gui key mapping with if statements

Tags: vim

I'm new to vim and loving it! Just wanted to reach out and get some help with my .vimrc file.

I'm trying to set F11 to make my gvim window larger. Here's the relevant code:

```
if has("gui_running")
  set guioptions-=m
  set guioptions-=r
  set lines=32 columns=132
  nnoremap <F11> :set lines=39 columns=169 <Enter>
  vnoremap <F11> :set lines=39 columns=169 <Enter>
  autocmd FocusLost * silent! :wa
endif
```

Once I hit F11 it grows to the bigger size (almost full screen on my machine) but when I hit F11 again nothing happens...obviously : )

I'd like to make F11 toggle that larger size with the smaller size. I'm not sure of the right way to do it, I'm very new at scripting vim.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom toggle function and map `F11` to that. I don't use gvim and didn't test this, but I'm pretty certain it should work:

```
function! ToggleGvimSize()
    if g:gvim_large
        set lines=32 columns=132
        let g:gvim_large = 0
    else
        set lines=39 columns=169
        let g:gvim_large = 1
    endif
endfunction

let g:gvim_large = 0
nnoremap <F11> :call ToggleGvimSize()
```

Put the above in your `.vimrc`. Now pressing `F11` should toggle your window size. Change the parameters and logic as per your needs.

Comment: Yes. Vimscript is different but not that different.